# VBA Export subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

Im trying to on button export a subform but all I am getting it various errors mostly It cant seem to recognize the subform object. The closest I am I think is the following :

```
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, Me.Form.<Subform_name>.Name, acFormatXLSX, savefileas, True
```

subform_name is the object name in the main form
Subform_form the source form

the sub form doesn't come from a separate query but record set is set from VBA of the parent form

The error on this vba is 2102 = "the form name  is misspelled or refers to a form that doesn't exist."

savefileas =

```
    Public Function savefileas() As String
Dim fd As FileDialog, filename As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

 Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

 If fd.Show = True Then
     If fd.SelectedItems(1) <> vbNullString Then
         filename = fd.SelectedItems(1)
     End If
 Else
     'Stop Code Execution for Null File String
     End
 End If
 savefileas = filename & ".xlsx"

 'Cleanup
 Set fd = Nothing
 Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
 Set fd = Nothing
 MsgBox "Error " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)
 End Function
```

Comment: Try to use `Me.<Subform_name>.SourceObject` instaed of `Me.Form.<Subform_name>.Name`

Comment: That works thank you, it is however showing the complete list though and not the displayed list which has been filtered by the parent forms setting of record source. I guess that is due to setting it to pull the raw subform rather than the nested one with the crafted record source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this working how I want now thanks to nudge from Andre, may not be the most efficient method but im getting the results I want.

To help any others that may come to this for a similar solution.

Im exporting to csv which was my ideal format I wanted.
Export button :

```
    Private Sub Command2_Click()
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, exportcsv, "export_query", savefileas, True

End Sub
```

On Open

```
    Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim strSQL As String
Dim export_query As QueryDef
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = <sql statement as defined by set record code>

<code that sets my subform record source> 

Set export_query = db.QueryDefs("Export_Query")
export_query.SQL = strSQL    
End Sub
```

Then each filter on update is a copy of the on open, so its setting the query used for export each time its setting the subform recordset IE what is shown.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is going to work.

`DoCmd.OutputTo` wants to open the object standalone, then export it.
The second parameter, `ObjectName` is not an object reference, but the object name.

It doesn't work on an already open object, even less on a subform with modified recordsource.

A better way is to create a temporary querydef with the subform's recordsource.
Then export this query.

Comment: I am already building a temp query really to set the subform record source so if I just add to that to set the querydef Id just need to call it to export.  Ill experiment now and report back

Comment: thank you for pushing me the correct way ive posted the full steps to get it working for others benefit